# Avoid passing RequestContext in every render in django

Tags: python, django

I am developing a site right now that, once you are logged in, a search bar will always be present on the top of the page. I am wondering what the best way design this paradigm in Django. Currently, I have a separate file called forms.py that sits at `settings.py` level in my folder hierarchy. In almost every view, I have to add:

```
from forms.py import SearchForm
```

and then in every single render call, I have to pass:

```
form = SearchForm()
return render('somepage.html',{"search_form" : form},c=RequestContext())
```

I have looked around for a better way of doing this, but I am having trouble finding anything useful. I have a feeling that the current design I am using is not ideal, since I am required to import/pass as parameter in almost every view.

The form is defined in a `base.html`, so I am using template inheritance, but I still need to pass the form object to every render as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

#### [Use a context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext)

Add your search form to the context of all views using `RequestContext`, which the new `render` you're using does automatically.

```
def FormContextProcessor(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return {'form': SearchForm() }
    return {}
```

You said it's used in nearly all views, and this is hardly an expensive operation instantiating a form, so I'd use this solution.

Comment: but this solution is not addressing second part of the code - rendering

Comment: Rendering is a non issue: "The form is defined in a base.html, so I am using template inheritance"

Comment: not template itself, but calling a template, "return render..." part

Comment: Calling `render`, specifying a template, and returning the result is a part of every django template-involved response and not a part of the problem :)

Comment: still, you do not understand, your solution adress only a part of the problem. simple as is. eot.

Answer (score 0):

with django < 1.3 you can have a decorator, which can take care of rendering a html:

```
def search_render(function):
   # return a decorated function which will take template from the args
   # take output of the inner function (this should be a dictionary e.g. data = ..
   # instantiate SearchForm
   # add SearchForm instance to the data dictionary
   # and return render(template, data, RequestContext(request))

@search_render(tamplate='somepage.html')
def my_other_view(request):
   return {'data':'value'}
```

With django >= 1.3 you can use a class based views, with similiar approach.